# How to remove a key from SortedDictionary

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

To build a heap tree I used SortedDictionay and named it "heap". After some process on first node (Key) I want to delete (remove) the first key so I use "heap.Remove(heap.Keys.First());". It runs but nothing changes! it means the first node is still there.

This is class `Task`:

```
public class Task : IComparable<Task>
{
    public int d_ij = 0;

    public List<slice> slices = new List<slice>();

    public class slice
    {
        public int slice_id = 0;
        public float start = 0;
        public float end = 0;
        public float speed = 0;
    }

    #region IComparable<Task> Members

    public int CompareTo(Task other)
    {
        if (this.slices[0].start > other.slices[0].start) return 1;
        else return -1;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This is the main function (in class of Program.cs)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Sid = 1;
    int Preid = 0;
    string LINE = "";
    string[] tmp_line;
    string[] tmp_tmp_line;

    SortedDictionary<Task, float> heap = new SortedDictionary<Task, float>();            

    Stream Tsk_info;
    Tsk_info = File.OpenRead(@"F:\...\info.txt");
    StreamReader TSK_INF = new StreamReader(Tsk_info);

    while (TSK_INF.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        LINE = TSK_INF.ReadLine();
        tmp_line = LINE.Split(' ');

        Task newtask = new Task();

        newtask.d_ij = Int16.Parse(tmp_line[0]);

        while (Sid < (tmp_line.Length)/2)
        {
            tmp_tmp_line = tmp_line[2 * Sid].Split('(', ')', ',');
            newtask.slices.Add(new Task.slice()
            {
                slice_id = Sid,
                start = float.Parse(tmp_tmp_line[1]),
                end = float.Parse(tmp_tmp_line[2]),
                speed = float.Parse(tmp_line[Sid + Preid])
            });

            Preid = Sid;
            Sid++;
        }

        Sid = 1;
        Preid = 0;
        heap.Add(newtask, newtask.slices[0].start);
    }          

    ///////THE PROBLEM IS HERE I CANNOT REMOVE FROM MY SORTED DICTIONARY
    bool u =  heap.Remove(heap.First().Key);
}
```

Comment: What does `Remove` return? From your description it sounds like this should work - can you post your code?

Comment: it just runs and continue...and when I check after "heap.remove(...)" the heap still is as same as before....

Comment: Why is it that difficult to put my code here...every time it is getting messy and doesn't have enough space..

Comment: BTW, the remove returns false! Please help me by that..it is a long time i am stuck on it ..no results!

Comment: You probably need to implement [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) for the sorted dictionary to compare if two objects are equal.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` only returns 1 and -1, never 0, even when comparing a Task to itself, as a result, the dictionary can't remove any item, as it is never able to find the item matching the item you are trying to remove (i.e. for which `CompareTo(itemToRemove)` returns 0).

Editing your implementation of `CompareTo()` so that it returns 0 when the items are the same should resolve the problem.

You should also take careful note of the following remark on MSDN regarding the [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

> Keys must be immutable as long as they are used as keys in the SortedDictionary. Every key in a SortedDictionary must be unique. A key cannot be null, but a value can be, if the value type TValue is a reference type.

Your `Task` class is not currently immutable, and adding an item at the start of the `slices` list, or changing the first item's `start` field would likely cause problems. You don't appear to do that in the code given (though you may do elsewhere), but it would still be better to programmatically prevent it from occurring, by making `Task` and `slice` immutable.